# Make my webpage access the web using my users IP address

Tags: asp.net, server, ip

I need my asp webpage to access other pages but I need it to do so on my users IP. I tried making one page which requests whatismyip and it would return the user's IP, meaning not my server's IP. So every unique user that visits my page will see the result of whatismyip as if they had accessed it through their browser.

So does this mean that all the requests done in this way would go through my users' IP and not my server?

**UPDATE:**

If I call this function then it should make a client request. So if I do this will the page at "theUrl" be able to see that the request is related to my webpage in any way?

```
<script>
    function httpGet(theUrl) {
        var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlHttp.open("GET", theUrl, true); // true for asynchronous request
        xmlHttp.send(null);
        return xmlHttp.responseText;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: A request starts from your server will use your server's IP. To generate a request from your user's IP, use JavaScript in the web page to trigger a client side request from the browser.

Comment: @LexLi Thanks for the comment, I updated my question can you look at it?